# Why does the getTime() function from cplex concert returns wrong value?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, concert, runtime

I am running a MILP formulation (implemented in C++) with the Cplex Concert Technology 12.10, and I am trying to get the total elapsed time. So till the moment, I have tried three approaches:
Be `cplex` my IloCplex object.

1. Using the `clock()` function from the `time.h` C++ library:

```
    cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, time_limit);
    time_t start = clock();
    cplex.solve();
    double total_time = (double) (clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

2. Using the Cplex Concert function `getTime()`:

```
    cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, time_limit);
    cplex.solve();
    double total_time = cplex.getTime();
```

3. Using the Cplex Concert parameter `ClockType`:

```
    cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, time_limit);
    cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::ClockType, 2);
    cplex.solve();
    double total_time = cplex.getTime();
```

My code **does not** make use of any callbacks (informational callback neither), and does not set any value to the Cplex Concert parameter `Threads`, i.e., the piece of code `cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Threads, n);` is not executed. Since such piece of code is not executed, then (according to the Cplex Concert official [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/Threads.html)) my code is using all available threads:

> When this parameter is at its default setting 0 (zero), and your
> application includes no callbacks or only an informational callback,
> CPLEX can use all available threads.

The problem that I am facing is that in all these three approaches the `total_time` presents a wrong value. For example, if I set the variable `time_limit` to `120`, i.e., set the optimization time limit to `120` seconds, then the variable `total_time` presents a value much bigger than the expected one, such as `892.322`.

So, I'd like to know if anyone already faced this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution can be found here [c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs).

Since you do not limit the threads, Cplex will span as many as there are cores. 
You are counting the cpu time (and since each core contributes all of its running time) you see a much larger value. I think you are interested in the wall-time of the process.

$892/120 \approx 7.4$. So i guess you have 8 cores (or 4 with hyperthreading). 
When you limit the threads to 1 you should see a value of about 120.

Comment: Very thank you.