# Calculated CPU time of C++ is different from actual time to solve MILP model via Gurobi

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, c++

I am solving a MILP model in C++ using Gurobi 7.5.2. More specifically, I am determining the CPU time of my C++ program via the following commands:

- clock_t start_time;
- double elapsed_time;
- start_time= clock();
- model.optimize();
- elapsed_time = (double) (clock() - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

When I compare the elapsed_time with the Gurobi runtime, the Gurobi runtime does show the actual duration (measured by a chronometer) but the calculated elapsed_time of C++ is way higher. Why is the elapsed_time not the same as the Gurobi runtime and the actual duration (measured by the chronometer)?

Comment: Do you use multiple cores?

Comment: Yes, I use 2 cores

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4238/why-does-the-gettime-function-from-cplex-concert-returns-wrong-value/4245#4245

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a C++ question, so you should rather look for similar questions on stackoverflow.

A common issue is that clock() is not accurate for short durations, so you may want one of the high resolution C++ timers instead, as shown in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c).

EDIT: as commented by user3680510 and Stradivari, this is due to the use of multithreading, as clock() [measures the CPU time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs). The C++ timer above (or C's time()) will behave correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`clock()` measures CPU time instead of real time. In order to measure real time in C++ use:

`auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`

`//do stuff`

`auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`

`auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();`